# django: raise validation error from another view

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have a template (new_user.html) that represents a view called 'new_user'. The view contains a form with few fields and validation for the data. Validation error messages are shown, if any, within the template. No problems here.

But if I'll add an include tag for another view in the same template, I cannot see the validation error messages for the new form. Validation errors work if the view is viewed separately (http://localhost:8000\modify_attr)

include tag in new_user.html

```
<div id="modify_attr">
    {% include "modify_attr.html" %}
</div>
```

modify_attr.html contains the following:

```
<table>
<form action="/modify_attr/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
    <td align="left"{{ field.label_tag }}</font></td>
    <td align="left">{{ field }}</td>
    <td align="left">
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% for err in field.errors %}
                <font color="red">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ err }}</font>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="update" class="button" name="modify_attr"/></td>
</tr>
```

views:

```
def modify_attr(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("modify_attr", "") == 'update':
        modform = modForm(request.POST, prefix='mod_attr')

        if modform.is_valid():
            # do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modify_attr'))

    else:
        modform = modForm(prefix='mod_attr')

    return render(request, 'modify_attr.html', {'modform': modform})

def new_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("create_user", "") == 'apply':  
        form = NameForm(request.POST, prefix='new_user')
        modform = modForm(prefix='mod_attr')

        if form.is_valid():      
            # do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_user'))

    else:
        form = NameForm(prefix='new_user')
        modform = modForm(prefix='mod_attr')

    return render(request, 'new_user.html', {'form': form,
                                     'modform': modform})
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: include the error message you are getting please.

Comment: there's no error I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer here is to return the form instead of rendering them to templates. For example:

```
return render(request, 'modify_attr.html', {'modform': modform})
```

is just:

```
return modform
```